# Clear the cache for jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I think I have read every stackoverflow and google result available on this issue and they all seem to refer to the first jquery autocomplete plugin and not the current jquery ui autocomplete.

What is the method for forcing the autocomplete results to update from the data source instead of the cached list?

Comment: how does your code look like? afaik, autocomplete has no internal cache mechanism. you build your own.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The jquery ui autocomplete does not do any caching. The caching is happening at the browser level. To prevent it from happening, use `$.ajaxSetup`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

You could also instead supply a function to the source option that does the ajax request for you with `cache: false` if you don't want to disable caching globally.

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        data: { term: request.term }
    }).done(function(data) {
        response(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a random [cache busting parameter](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/cachebuster-code-in-javascript/) to the source url that jQuery UI uses. jQuery UI is smart enough to handle appending the term parameter if there's already a cache busting parameter there.