# Jquery Autocomplete remembers the previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

The requirement is to display autocomplete addresses based on the region selected. The Jquery autocomplete is called everytime the region changes. I am getting the correct autocomplete addresses based on the region. But along with the new address list, I also get the address list for previously selected regions.
To solve this problem, I used -   $("#address).removeData('events').autocomplete(...)

This solves the problem. But a new problem is introduced now! The scrolling in the autocomplete list does not work properly, items are skipped on pressing down arrow key/up arrow key.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$("#address).removeData('events').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl : 'mysource',
    minChars : 2,
    params : {
        region : selectedRegion
    },
    noCache : true,
    width : 350,
    maxHeight : 170,
    onSelect : function (value) {
        ...
        ...
    }
});
```

Can somebody suggest me the correct approach? I am using jquey.autocomplete-min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the following worked like a charm to me

```
var ac = $("#address").autocomplete();
```

The next time, the region is changed, instead of calling `autocomplete()`
 again, I just do this -

```
   ac.setOptions({ params:{ region : selectedRegion}});
```

This updates the existing call with new region. I will no more see autocomplete suggestions for the previous selections.

Answer (score 0):

If youre getting an additional appearing alongside jquery's autocomplete list, it may be an issue with your browser trying to autocomplete the input.
trying adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the input field you're autocompleting

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried this. But it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726146/1304575) the issue might not be with your code snippet but with browser http caching in general.