# jQuery autocomplete issue on repeat when barcode scanner is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using `jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` and `jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js`
for web POS I'm programming. I have an input field named "search".

```
$("#search").autocomplete({...

...response: function( event, ui ) {
      if (ui.content.length == 1)
      {
           if($('#pme-' + ui.content[0].id).length > 0){
                increaseItems(ui.content[0].id,1);
            } else {
                createElement(ui.content[0]);
            }
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).autocomplete( "close" );
            $(this).data().term = null;
       }
    },....
```

So when only one element is found, the script is adding the item to the cart. If multiple items it shows a dropdown (not shown here)

It works great with a barcode reader, but if you scan the same barcode again, there will be no second ajax call. If another barcode - it works. So somehow autocomplete doesn't work on repeat input.

Is there any way to work around this?

I've tried [Clear the cache for jquery ui autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726089/clear-the-cache-for-jquery-ui-autocomplete) this solution to disable ajax cache, but no luck as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if its good solution, but I was able to fix this issue by sending an empty call after item has been added to the cart - `$(this).autocomplete("search", "");`

```
response: function( event, ui ) {
      if (ui.content.length == 1)
      {
           if($('#pme-' + ui.content[0].id).length > 0){
                increaseItems(ui.content[0].id,1);
            } else {
                createElement(ui.content[0]);
            }
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).autocomplete( "close" );
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
       }
    },
```